# Android check firebase connection

Tags: android, database, firebase, database-connection

I am using a firebase database for my Android app.
When I submit a score there is a message (fragment serverOK) if it works.
I would like a message for all the other cases. There is one if the databaseEror is non null but how to do if it didn't connect to firebase?

Below is my code:

```
ref.setValue(resultat, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference dataRef) {
        if (databaseError == null) {
           FragmentManager fm3 = getFragmentManager();
           ServerOk serverok = new ServerOk();
           serverok.show(fm3, "serverok");
        } else {
           FragmentManager fm3 = getFragmentManager();
           Server server = new Server();
           server.show(fm3, "server");
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you for you answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Firebase client doesn't treat the absence of a connection as an error, so it doesn't call your completion listener with an error.

When you call `setValue()` while the Firebase client is not connected to its backend, the client keeps the write in a queue. When the connection is restored, it sends the write to the server.

Your completion handler will only be called once the write has been executed by the server. If there was an error (i.e. if the security rules rejected the write), you will get an error passed into the callback.

If you want to know if the client is connected to the server before calling `setValue()`, you can [attach a listener to `.info/connected`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is really useful!

Comment: hello @FrankvanPuffelen, i have a problem with the code show in the documentation link you provided for detecting the connection status, some time my app throw a NullPointerException in this method, i analyze my code with android studio and he show me this "Unboxing of 'snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'" you know how can i fix it?, thanks

Comment: Sorry, i think i solve with this: `Boolean connected = Boolean.FALSE;
                if(snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class) != null){
                    connected =  snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                }`

Answer (score 3):

Did you try adding onFailureListner?

```
ref.setValue(resultat, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference dataRef) {
        if (databaseError == null) {
           FragmentManager fm3 = getFragmentManager();
           ServerOk serverok = new ServerOk();
           serverok.show(fm3, "serverok");
        } else {
           FragmentManager fm3 = getFragmentManager();
           Server server = new Server();
           server.show(fm3, "server");
        }
    }
})
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             // did not set value
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseError

You can check the error type with `databaseError.getCode()` and then test it against those listed there. For debugging you can also use `databaseError.getMessage()` or `databaseError.getDetails()` to get information. You can also print it as a `StackTrace` with `databaseError.toException().printStackTrace()`.

In your case I guess `databaseError.getCode() == DatabaseError.DISCONNECTED` or `databaseError.getCode() == DatabaseError.NETWORK_ERROR`, but I am not sure about those. You can just test it yourself. You can of course also just print the code for debugging purposes.

Comment: problem is that firebase doesn't throw an error when you are not connected to the internet. Therefore, if the data is not written to firebase, the error is not thrown. Therefore, all what you say does not apply.

Comment: I know that this is true for Firestore and it would make sense to be true for the Realtime Database as well, but I wonder what the `DatabaseError.DISCONNECTED` value describes then. Also you need to consider that he was asking for all other cases, i.e. all errors and not only internet.

Comment: Yes you are right for the DatabaseError.DISCONNECTED .. it wouldn't make sense if disconnecting would would not throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try including this com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0 in dependencies