# Why is data in Realtime database not writing with no error in logcat Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

```
    fun updateDatabse(num:String, titlexp:String, gorl:String)
    {
        val expID=dbref.push().key!!
         val expense=expenseModel(titlexp,num.toInt(),gorl)
//DataNotAdding after executing the following line the debug cursor exits the function
         dbref.child("expenses").child(expID).setValue(expense)
            .addOnSuccessListener{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Expense Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }.addOnFailureListener{err->
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Expense not added due to error ${err.message}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

    }
}
```

[image: Firebase console image]
Also, I have already allowed for Internet and access network state permission in Android Manifest.xml
My rules in the console are as follows:-

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,  
    ".write": true, 
  }
}
```

Comment: Found the fix to the problem by following this advice https://stackoverflow.com/a/45772852/20692036

Comment: Thanks for letting us know the fix Raunak. That's indeed a common problem nowadays, and it's hard to troubleshoot since the task neither succeeds nor fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you have to do is check in logcat for message or not connected with respect to FirebaseDatabase and if it comes to not connected just simply delete google-services.json found in project files under app ->build->google-services.json. Once you delete this file just simply close Android Studio and connect again using the FireBaseAssistant found in tools->Firebase-> then RealTimeDatabase. This will most probably fix the issue as it did for me as well.